# Problem with SQL code: Subquery returns more than 1 row:

Tags: mysql

I have two tables which are "authors" and "listened" and, what I am trying to do is count how many books I have listened to by a particular author and then get the last book I listened to by that author. The code I have is:

```
SELECT COUNT(`listened`.`id`) AS `count`, `authors`.`name` AS `author`, (SELECT `title` FROM `listened` WHERE `author` = `authors`.`id` ORDER BY `read` DESC) AS `last` FROM `authors` INNER JOIN `listened` ON `authors`.`id` = `listened`.`author` GROUP BY `listened`.`author`;
```

This code results in the following error:

```
 #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

My problem is that I can't figure out how to rewrite it and the previous answers here do not seem to help.

Comment: Can you add the table schema of the 2 rables and please fix the sql code. Make it a multi line instead of a very long one line.

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `authors` (`id` SMALLINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
 `name` VARCHAR(160) NOT NULL UNIQUE) 
 ENGINE=INNODB;
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `listened` (`id` INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
 `read` DATE NOT NULL, 
 `author` SMALLINT NOT NULL, 
 `title` VARCHAR(160) NOT NULL, 
 `series` VARCHAR(160) NOT NULL, `
 position` SMALLINT NOT NULL, 
 FOREIGN KEY (`author`) REFERENCES `authors` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) ENGINE = INNODB;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use LIMIT 1 for get on one row

```
SELECT COUNT(`listened`.`id`) AS `count`
    , `authors`.`name` AS `author`
    , ( SELECT `title` 
        FROM `listened` 
        WHERE `author` = `authors`.`id` 
        ORDER BY `read` DESC 
        LIMIT  1 
    ) AS `last` 
FROM `authors` INNER JOIN `listened` ON `authors`.`id` = `listened`.`author` 
GROUP BY `listened`.`author`;
```

Anyway you could avoid the limit 1 subquery using a join on a subqoery for max(read) group by author

```
SELECT COUNT(`listened`.`id`) AS `count` 
    , `authors`.`name` AS `author`
    , listened.title
from FROM `authors` 
INNER JOIN  (
    select author, max(read) max_read
    FROM listened 
    GROUP BY author

    ) t ON t.author = `authors`.`id`
        and t.max_read = listened.read
INNER JOIN `listened` ON `authors`.`id` = `listened`.`author` 
GROUP BY `listened`.`author`;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(`listened`.`id`) AS `count`, `authors`.`name` AS `author`, 
(SELECT `title` FROM `listened` WHERE `author` = `authors`.`id` ORDER BY `read` DESC limit 1) AS `last` 
FROM `authors` INNER JOIN `listened` ON `authors`.`id` = `listened`.`author` 
GROUP BY `listened`.`author`;
```

Add limit 1 to your subquery.